# How to keep all the data on my applications when I buy a new iPad

Tags: ipad, applications, data

I am buying a new iPad because I only have a 16gb iPad and I want to keep the data on my apps ie. on sims I want to keep the houses and people on it but is it possible to do that when you buy a new iPad and sell the one that has the apps and data that you want to keep? Thanks and sorry if that's confusing?

Comment: How do you currently backup you iPad, via iTunes, iCloud or not at all?

Answer (score 1):

1. Run iTunes on your computer.
2. Connect old (16GB) iPad to computer with USB cable.
3. Back up iPad to iTunes/computer. Do not erase old iPad yet.
4. Disconnect old iPad.
5. Connect new iPad to iTunes/computer with USB cable.
6. Restore settings from old iPad onto new.
7. Disconnect new iPad.

Once you're sure the new iPad has everything you expect on it (all app data, etc.) then you can connect old iPad to iTunes and restore to factory settings wiping it out so you can sell it, give it away, or recycle it with Apple.

Comment: This didn't work. I just got a replacement iPad3. Before I took in my old one I followed your instructions. Now I have a new iPad (same model). I picked restore. Zero apps and zero app data have been restored. Many of the apps that were on my old iPad had lots of data. How do I get it back? The screenshot for the backup even shows the home screen with all the apps.